# using EXEC SYS.DBMS_STATS.LOCK_TABLE_STATS command on multiple users

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I need to execute the query

`EXEC SYS.DBMS_STATS.LOCK_TABLE_STATS('MCCANE', 'SDE_LOGFILE_DATA');`

for multiple users at the same time (MCCANE being one of the user). Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: What is wrong with running multiple `LOCK_TABLE_STATS` commands sequentially, one for each user?

Comment: Yes, I understood, but I was looking for an alternative, if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to do the same for all tables (that share the same name) in your database. If that's so, write a piece of code that'll make it possible. In order to do that,

- loop through `DBA_TABLES`,
- search for user (i.e. *owner*) who owns such a table,
- compose a statement (into my `L_STR` variable),
- display it first (to make sure it is correctly written) and - if it is -
- run it as dynamic SQL (`execute immediate`).

Here's an example; I'm doing it with the `DEPT` table (as I don't have `SDE_LOGFILE_DATA`).

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_str varchar2(100);
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select owner from dba_tables
  5                  where table_name = 'DEPT'
  6                 )
  7    loop
  8      l_str := q'[sys.dbms_stats.lock_table_stats(']' || cur_r.owner || q'[', 'DEPT')]';
  9      l_str := 'begin ' || l_str ||'; end;';
 10      dbms_output.put_line(l_str);     -- if everything's OK, comment this ...
 11      -- execute immediate l_str;      -- ... and uncomment that
 12    end loop;
 13  end;
 14  /
begin sys.dbms_stats.lock_table_stats('MIKE', 'DEPT'); end;
begin sys.dbms_stats.lock_table_stats('HR', 'DEPT'); end;
begin sys.dbms_stats.lock_table_stats('SCOTT', 'DEPT'); end;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: The query is being generated as expected, but when using execute immediate, am getting an error :                                                                                                                           `Error report:
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 9
00900. 00000 -  "invalid SQL statement"
*Cause:    
*Action:`. Is it because of privilege issue of the user ? However, am able to run `EXEC SYS.DBMS_STATS.LOCK_TABLE_STATS` with the same user

Comment: Ah! It is PL/SQL; L_STR's result should be enclosed into BEGIN - END. I fixed it (I hope!), check line #9 and the output.